# Repo with sources for Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, php-7, repository

Where is the source code repo for Magento 1? I want to post PHP7 incompatibility fix for the latest version (1.9.2.4).

Answer (score 2):

Unlike Magento 2, there is no official Magento 1 repo where you can do pull requests.

On a side note, Inchoo released a free module that makes Magento 1 compatible with PHP 7: https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7